# Automate CI/CD using .json script

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I checked AzureDevopsDemoGenerator. I have two .json files for creating CI/CD pipeline.

I want to know how to push this to Azure DevOps Demo Generator to check this. We don't want to use the ARM. Any external utility through which I can push it and pipeline is automatically created.

Comment: sorry, its unclear what you are asking, there is no such thing as a json script

Comment: I mean ARM templates. But I want to be able to push to Azure from external utility.

Answer (score 1):

az cli, azure powershell, azure sdk (c#, java, python, etc), rest api. all of those can do that.  on top of that: ansible, terraform, pulumi and probably some others can do that.

all of these are easily googleable.

Comment: Actually, I want to push the template to AzureDevopsDemoGenerator first.

Comment: i think this would be a completely different question